# Cypress Automation cannot assert Adobe Analytics

Tags: cypress, adobe, analytics, cypress-intercept

I am using Cypress automation, at the moment I am testing/writing tests for Analytics.

With Google Analytics I was easily able to write my tests using cy.intercept() function and was successfully able to assert Google Analytics. But... with Adobe Analtics the cy.intercept() function doesn't see Adobe Analytics. I been researching solutions with no luck,

1. there is very little info
2. their solutions suggest to use cy.interept() which Cypress skips over the Adobe call. Here is what I have so far:

The prior steps are to login the website and turn on Adobe Analytics. Then I am supposed to assert that Adobe Analytics are up and running. I am using this:

```
        cy.intercept('POST', 'https://securetags.esri.com/b/ss/esri.researchdev.turner/1/JS-2.23.0/s', { statusCode: 200 }).as('adobe-analytics')

        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.log('**Step 6**')
        cy.waitForStableDOM({timeout: 55000})
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.wait('@adobe-analytics').get('@adobe-analytics')
        .then((xhr) =>{
            console.log("Adobe-Analytics Response:", xhr)
            
        })
```

Where it fails is at cy.wait('@adobe-analytics') and the response I get that the 1sst request to the route: @adobe-analytics no request ever occurred.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Adobe Analytics might be making XHR (XMLHttpRequest) requests instead of regular network requests. In such cases, cy.intercept() might not work. You can try using cy.route() instead, which is designed specifically for XHR interception.

Comment: @MuratIshen cy.intercept() supports XHR requests. Additionally, `cy.route()` was deprecated in Cypress 6 and I would not recommend using deprecated commands.

Comment: OP, have you tried intercepting a more generic URL and seeing if maybe your matcher is too specific? Something like `'**/esri.researchdev.turner/**'`?

Comment: thank you, I'll go ahead and try that right now.

Comment: didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

After researching and trying various things. I figured out what I was doing wrong. The way I had set up my cy.intercept() was incorrect.
Before:

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'https://securetags.e.com/b/ss/e.researchdev.turner/', {status: 200}).as('adobe-analytics')
```

but what it needed was this:

```js
cy.intercept('/b/ss/**').as('adobe-analytics')
```

Just that easy. Also note, it is extremely important where you add this or what area of the code you add this intercept on/at, be sure to try different areas, ie: before a button click, at the before() block, etc.
Hope this helps.